# Calculating a fiber product via a tensor product

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

I feel like this probably shouldn’t be as hard as I’m finding it… but in any case:

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $0$ (algebraically closed, if necessary, or even equal to $\mathbb{C}$), and let $B=k[t,t^{-1}]$. Let $A=k[x,x^{-1}]$ and $C=k[y,y^{-1}]$, and make $A$ and $C$ into $B$-modules by the maps given by $t\mapsto x^n$ and $t\mapsto y^m$ (so $t$ acts as $x^n$ on $A$ and as $y^m$ on $C$). I would like to compute the tensor product $A\otimes_B C$, but I’m not quite sure how to start. I know that $A$ and $C$ are flat over $B$ since $B$ is a PID and $A$ and $C$ are torsion-free as $B$-modules, so I was hoping to perhaps put $A$ and/or $C$ into a short exact sequence (e.g. $0\to M_1\to M_2\to A\to 0$) and then tensor with $C$ and use flatness to compute $A\otimes_B C$, but this didn’t seem to help very much since I can’t figure out how to pick $M_1$ and/or $M_2$ in such a way that I can easily compute $M_1\otimes_B C$ and $M_2\otimes_B C$.

Does anyone have any hints as to how to proceed? I would even be happy with hints focusing on cases like where $m=n$ or $m\mid n$, if the general case turns out to be messy.

For context, I am really trying to compute the fiber product $X\times_Y Z$ with $X=Y=Z=\mathbb{A}^1_k\setminus\{0\}$, where $X\to Y$ is given by $x\mapsto x^n$ and $Z\to Y$ by $x\mapsto x^m$. But I have very little geometric intuition (plus almost no actual background in algebraic geometry), so I was hoping to follow the algebra to the answer.

Comment: Have you tried identifying $A$ with $B[X,X^{-1}]/(X-t^n)$ as a $B$-algebra? (Here $B[X]$ is the polynomial algebra over B)

Comment: @I'mRepresentable Unfortunately, that identification doesn't hold: $$B[X^{\pm1}]/(X - t^n)\cong B[t^{\pm n}] = k[t^{\pm1},t^{\pm n}] = k[t^{\pm 1}] = B.$$

Comment: Oops, I meant to write modulo $(X^n-t)$.